# Search list with another list but stop on first match

Tags: python, loops

I have two lists, a short one and a longer one.

```
list1= ['one', 'two']
list2= ['ten', 'seven', 'three', 'one', 'eight', 'six', 'nine', 'two', 'four', 'five']
```

I need to search the long list for every word in the short list. If it finds a match, stop searching and do something. If it doesn't find it, do something else. The actual list can be quite long so if it finds it I don't want it to keep looking. The only part I can't figure out is getting it to stop once found. Maybe my search terms are wrong. How do I get it to stop search once found, return `None` if not found? What's the most efficient or pythonic way of doing this? Here is what I have (the fuzzy search is part of something else):

```
    for name in list1:
        for dict in reversed(list2):
            if fuzz.WRatio(name, dict['Number']) > 90:
```

I know I can add what to do when found and then `break` but then I'm not sure what to do if it isn't found except put in another `if` but now it's starting to seem kludgy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern you described is often designed to be a function of the form `def find(content, pattern) -> offset`.

You iterate over the candidates and find the first one matching the pattern, which in your case is by checking if it matches any string in the second list.

When there's no match found, this kind of function often returned `-1`, for example, the [string.find](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find) method in Python returns `-1` when nothing's found.

So in your case you may create a function like the following:

```
def find(candidates, patterns):
    for i, name in enumerate(candidates):
        for dict in reversed(patterns):
            if fuzz.WRatio(name, dict['Number']) > 90:
                return i # return the index of the name match a pattern
    return -1
```

Comment: Thanks, I think that's the best way for what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, maybe code like this is what you want.

```
list1 = ['one', 'two']
list2 = ['ten', 'seven', 'three', 'one', 'eight', 'six', 'nine', 'two', 'four', 'five']

list1_count = 0
for name1 in list1:
  for name2 in list2:
    if name1 == name2:
      list1_count = list1_count + 1
      break

if list1_count == len(list1):
  print("found")
else:
  print("not found")
```

Lines from `list1_count = 0` to `break` can be (maybe more Pythonically) replaced to:

```
list1_count = 0
for name1 in list1:
  if name1 in list2:
    list1_count = list1_count + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand what you're looking for, but something that finds the first value and stops it

```
list1 = ['one', 'two']
list2 = ['ten', 'seven', 'three', 'one', 'eight', 'six', 'nine', 'two', 'four', 'five']

for l in list1:
    a = list2.index(l)
    break

print(a)
```

---

If you want to return None if you find nothing, try

```
list1 = ['one', 'two']
list2 = ['ten', 'seven', 'three', 'one', 'eight', 'six', 'nine', 'two', 'four', 'five']

try:
    for l in list1:
        a = list2.index(l)
        break
except:
    a = None

print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will tell you if all of the values from `list1` are in `list2`.

```
all_in = all([val in list2 for val in list1])
```

If all of the values from `list1` are in `list2`, the value of `all_in` will be `True`, and if they weren't, the value of `all_in` will be `False`.

If you wanted, you could use this line directly to control your if-else logic.

```
if all([val in list2 for val in list1]):
    #do thing if match
else:
    #do thing if no match
```

### Edit

If you were looking for the first match of any word in the first list, this might be closer to what you were looking for.

This will give you a `True` value if there is any match from the first list in the second. Again you can use this for an if statement.

```
any_in = any((val in list2 for val in list1))
```

If you need the value of the first match, or a None value if no match is found, this should work.

```
first_match = next((val for val in list1 if val in list2), None)
```

That will make use of Python's generators to stop on the very first matching case of any of the words in the first list.

### Edit 2

I think I'm pretty sure that the behavior that you were trying to describe was nesting the loops.

```
for val in list1:
    if val in list2:
        #do something
    else:
        #do something else
```

Comment: I do need to evaluate them individually, not all or nothing.

Comment: Does this mean you need to perform some behavior when each word from the first list is in the second list? I'm confused about what you want to do when you say you want to stop the search once found. Do you need the values of the words that matched? Do you only care about the first match?

Comment: Using the example I gave, it should search list2 for `one`. If it finds it, do something. If it doesn't, do something else. Then it will search list2 for `two`. If it finds it, do something, else do something else. It's not trying to see if ALL the words in list1 are in list2 collectively but individually.